# Removing Eclipse completely

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

I had an Eclipse - Galileo working fine . Suddenly it started to hang till death(eclipse crashes) when I tried to open a DB2 table form DbViewer Plugin's Db tree View . I tried many stuffs , replacing DbViewer plugin and other memory stuffs . This happens only with DBViewer.

So I unziped another eclipse in another directory . But it opens the same settings,plugins and workspace of the previous eclipse .I removed the previous eclipse even the same problem exists.

In simple word. How to remove eclipse completely from Windows 7?

Comment: I completely removed the .metadata folder and along with my workspace .A fresh new copy of eclipse is working .

Comment: Also remove `.eclipse` and `.m2` in your home directory.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov The `.m2` directory is for Maven and not eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these directories need to be deleted to achieve complete removal of Eclipse:

1. Eclipse folder (Eclipse not installed, only copied directory. This directory need to be  deleted)
2. `.eclipse` and `.metadata` directories

If you don't want to use your previous workspace, you can delete it too.