# How do I completely remove a multiuser Eclipse installation from a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, uninstall

I have a corrupted multiuser installation of Eclipse Standard 4.3.1 (Kepler) on my Windows 7 PC.  I want to completely remove it so that I can do a fresh installation.  I am looking for a solution that does not involve a third-party software removal tool.

I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/532379/217195) here on SU, but it has only partial answers.

I searched the various resources on the [Eclipse site](http://www.eclipse.org/)—the forums, the documentation/help, and Eclipsepedia—but I could not find a complete answer.

Comment: it might not be helpful in this case since you've already taken steps  in uninstalling and removing it from the directories, but Revo Uninstaller is a fantastic free tool that does a lot of this dirty work, in addition to scrubbing the registry for you.

http://www.revouninstaller.com/

Comment: @worseone: Thanks, but I was really looking for a solution that did not require third-party software removal tools.  However, I forgot to mention that in my original question.  I've updated the question accordingly.  I apologize for not being completely clear in my original question.  Also, I've removed my uninstallation steps from the question because my answer made them redundant.

Comment: no sweat, feel free to mark your answer as the best answer if you found the appropriate result. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Eclipse documentation, an [article](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html?cp=2_1_3_7) describes the storage locations that are important in a multiuser setup.  Based on that article and my own experience, I created the following instructions.  Please note that the instructions assume that the default storage locations have not been customized.

**Before proceeding, make sure that you have backed up any important Eclipse data, such as projects stored in workspaces.**

To completely remove a multiuser Eclipse installation from a Windows 7 PC, do the following:

- Delete the installation directory (that is, the directory that contains
  `eclipse.exe`).
- For each user who has run Eclipse at least once, delete the `.eclipse` and
  `workspace` directories from the user's home directory (the root of the
  user's profile).

(Note: Unlike many Windows applications, [Eclipse does not change the Windows registry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_I_get_and_install_Eclipse%3F#Installing_Eclipse).  As a result, you do not need to do any registry cleanup when you remove Eclipse.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only thing you really need to worry about is deleting the installation directory. Because Eclipse does not integrate with the host system, you can quite easily maintain multiple installations in different directories without them conflicting (they might need to use different workspaces, however).

Comment: I already deleted the installation directory; what I am trying to do now is delete any leftover data and settings from my home directory.  So far, I have deleted `%userprofile%\.eclipse` and `%userprofile%\workspace`.  Do you know of any other default places where Eclipse stores its data and settings?  I just want to be confident that I have removed all traces of this corrupted installation so that I can start over with a fresh installation.

Comment: I don't even have `%userprofile%\.eclipse` on my machine. Eclipse just generally dumps everything into the workspace's `.metadata` folder.

Comment: If you don't have `%userprofile%\.eclipse` on your machine, then you probably have a single-user installation; `%userprofile%\.eclipse` is created only in multiuser installations, according to an [article](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html?cp=2_1_3_7) in the documentation.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that it's about removing a multiuser installation, as opposed to a single-user installation.